# Read JSON file before runtime on UNITY

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I develop a game and I have a "recorder system" that finds objects by their tags and saves their position and rotation in a JSON file and also saves their tags.

Then I have a scene that creates objects and gives the objects the position and rotation of the objects by the frame we are in.

Now, I want to use a specific prefab for every tag, so I need to read from the JSON what tags I record and to every tag give a prefab, but I want to do that with a SerializeField and I want it to happen before press on play.

Is there a way to read the JSON file and create a list while using a SerializeField before press play?

Comment: You cannot perform actions before the application is running. That would mean your application is able to figure out you are about to start it and then start ahead of that. This is why most if not all games have loading times, that's when all those pregame actions are performed.

Comment: @Everts of course you can do what OP is asking for ... it will just not make any sense in a build application as it only can happen within the editor ... OP is this what you are asking for?

Comment: You listen to [`EditorApplication.playModeStateChanged`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorApplication-playModeStateChanged.html) and check for [`PlayModeStateChange.ExitingEditMode`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayModeStateChange.ExitingEditMode.html), deserialize the json and save

Comment: the reason I want to do it is because I want to make the recorder feature as much modular that I can so I want the developer to add the tags on the editor once before running and also before build the project.
I want to use that as a sort of a setting of the project.

Comment: So just to confirm once again this is a pure editor side tool, right? So are you asking how to do the JSON part or is your question rather how to make sure it happens before entering play mode and probably more important before a build?

Comment: @derHugo yes you are right, It's should be a pure editor tool.
I already have a JSON file and I try to read this file before play mode/build.

Answer (score 2):

So as said for doing something before entering play mode you could e.g. attach a listener to [`EditorApplication.playModeStateChanged`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorApplication-playModeStateChanged.html) and check for [`PlayModeStateChange.ExitingEditMode`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayModeStateChange.ExitingEditMode.html) like e.g.

```
public static class Example
{
    [InitializeOnLoadMethod]
    private static void Init()
    {
        EditorApplication.playModeStateChanged -= LogPlayModeState;
        EditorApplication.playModeStateChanged += LogPlayModeState;
    }

    private static void LogPlayModeState(PlayModeStateChange state)
    {
        if(state == PlayModeStateChange.ExitingEditMode)
        {
            // TODO
        }
    }
}
```

In order to do the same right before a build you can implement [`IPreprocessBuildWithReport`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Build.IPreprocessBuildWithReport.html).

---

I would use a [`ScriptableObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ScriptableObject.html) for this so you can simply reference it anywhere you want and do e.g.

```
[CreateAssetMenu]
public class MyObject : ScriptableObject
#if UNITY_EDITOR
, IPreprocessBuildWithReport
#endif
{
    public List<Whatever>() yourList;

#if UNITY_EDITOR

    // Shared method for serialization
    private void JsonToList()
    {
        string json = /*Wherever you get your json from*/;
        yourList = /*However you deserialize the json into list*/;
        EditorUtility.SetDirty(this);
        AssetDatabase.SaveAssetIfDirty(this);
        AssetDatabase.Refresh();
    }

    // Implementation of the Build-Pre-Processor
    public void OnPreprocessBuild(BuildReport report)
    {
        JsonToList();
    }

    // Implementation for getting all PlayMode enters
    [InitializeOnLoadMethod]
    private static void Init()
    {
        EditorApplication.playModeStateChanged -= LogPlayModeState;
        EditorApplication.playModeStateChanged += LogPlayModeState;
    }
    
    private static void LogPlayModeState(PlayModeStateChange state)
    {
        if(state == PlayModeStateChange.ExitingEditMode)
        {
            // Find all instances of this ScripableObject and call the serialize method on them
            var guids = AssetDatabase.FindAssets($"t:{nameof(MyObject)}");
            foreach(var guid in guids)
            {
                var path = AssetDatabase.GUIDToAssetPath(guid);
                var asset = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath<MyObject>(path);
                asset.JsonToList();
            }
        }
    }
#endif
}
```